# Django-Filters with class-based views: Apply Django FilterSet dynamically

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I am using `django-filters` for filtering data on Class Based Viewset. I am using a `filter_class` on the class-based view which does the initial filtering of the viewsets. And I have a separate filter which filters output on demand.

**filters.py**

```
class BookingFilterBackend(DRYPermissionFiltersBase):
    def filter_list_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if request.user.is_role_admin:
            return queryset

        if request.user.is_role_client:
            return queryset.filter(Q(client=request.user.client))

        if request.user.is_role_camop:
            return queryset.filter(Q(camera_operator=request.user))

        return queryset.filter(Q(created_by=request.user))

class FilterOne(filters.FilterSet):
    title = filters.CharFilter(method=filter_booking_title)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Booking
        fields = [
            'title',
            'state',
            'client',
        ]


class FilterTwo(filters.FilterSet):
    client = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=users_models.Client.objects.all())

    state = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=constants.BookingState)

    camera_operator = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=users_models.UserManager.camop_users())

    date_start = filters.DateFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='startswith')

    date_end = filters.DateFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='endswith')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Booking
        fields = [
            'state',
            'client',
            'camera_operator',
            'date_start',
            'date_end',
        ]
```

**api.py**

```
class MyViewSet(
    MultipleSerializerMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    queryset = models.Booking.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [filters.BookingFilterBackend, DjangoFilterBackend, ]
    filter_class = filters.FilterOne
    pagination_class = BookingViewSetPagination
    serializer_class = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer

    serializer_classes = {
        ...            
    }

    @list_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='export-bookings')
    def export_bookings(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()

    // just some debugging code
    query_dict = request.data
    print(query_dict.get('state', []))
    print(query_dict.get('clients', []))
    print(query_dict.get('camera_operators', []))
    print(query_dict.get('from_date', ''))
    print(query_dict.get('to_date', ''))

    // Apply the filter set - FilterTwo - on my model objects -> Booking. Something like this:
    // filtered_queryset = filters.FilterTwo(queryset, query_dict) - ??

    return response.NoContent()
```

However, I can't figure out how to write that statement which calls the `FilterTwo` with `the query dictionary` (received in the body of POST call) and the original `queryset`.

Secondly, I have a `date` field in my modal and I want to perform greater_than and lesser_than on this field. I wonder whether my Filter logic is written correctly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after digging in a lot into django FilterBackends and `django_filters`'s FilterSets, I understood the concept and usage of both. Although, I've solved the problem it can definitely be improved further. (I'll post it as a separate question on SO).

This is the solution:
Instead of defining a new custom `FilterSet`, I had to create a new `FilterBackend` and override the `filter_queryset` method.

**filters.py**

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from dry_rest_permissions.generics import DRYPermissionFiltersBase
from rest_framework import filters as generic_filters

# Project Local
from . import models, constants
from shootsta.users import models as users_models


class BookingFilterBackend(DRYPermissionFiltersBase):
    def filter_list_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if request.user.is_role_admin:
            return queryset

        if request.user.is_role_client:
            return queryset.filter(Q(client=request.user.client))

        if request.user.is_role_camop:
            return queryset.filter(Q(camera_operator=request.user))

        return queryset.filter(Q(created_by=request.user))

# This is my new filter backend (I know the filtration logic looks very basic, I've come from a java background so spare me the rant.)
class MyNewFilterBackend(generic_filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        predicate = request.data

        if all(k in predicate for k in ('from_date', 'to_date')):
            queryset = queryset.filter(date__range=(predicate['from_date'], predicate['to_date']))

        if 'from_date' in predicate and 'to_date' not in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date__gte=predicate['from_date'])

        if 'to_date' in predicate and 'from_date' not in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date__lte=predicate['to_date'])

        if 'state' in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(state__in=predicate['state'])

        if 'clients' in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(client__in=predicate['clients'])

        if 'camera_operators' in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(camera_operator__uuid__in=predicate['camera_operators'])

        if 'recipients' in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(users__uuid__in=predicate['recipients'])

        return queryset
```

This is my api.py, where I just added this new filter backend to the list.

**api.py**

```
class MyViewSet(
    MultipleSerializerMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):

...

filter_backends = [filters.BookingFilterBackend, filters. MyNewFilterBackend, DjangoFilterBackend, ]
...


# This is the api which receives filteration form data from frontend.
@list_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='export-bookings')
def export_bookings(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()

    # filter results!
    filtered_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

    tasks.generate_export_data_and_notify_accounts(filtered_queryset)

    return response.NoContent()
```

I'm still wondering if I could achieve this using FilterSets.

Answer (score 3):

you can call the filter class filter_queryset method

```
 queryset = self.get_queryset()
 queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
```

Comment: it says: `AttributeError: 'FilterTwo' object has no attribute 'filter_queryset'`

Comment: sorry it's self.filter_queryset()

Comment: how is it going to judge which filter i want to call?

If you see my Class View:
`filter_backends = [filters.BookingFilterBackend, DjangoFilterBackend, ]`
`filter_class = filters.FilterOne`

These is different from what i want to use. Edit: my bad, i named them properly now.

Comment: it will apply all filter backend, if you have use specific filter then call with FilterBackendClass().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)

Comment: It doesn't work. FilterTwo() is not called.
Can you please check my `filters.py` again?

Comment: I've finally found the solution. Had to use filter backend instead of filter set. Thanks for the help though.